# How to substitute variable at lpSolveAPI in R

Tags: r, lpsolve

I'am doing solve the linear program by lpSolveAPI and I want to substitute object function's variable for subject to's variable.

for example, i mimic orignal my lp like this

```
x5 <- x1 + x2
x6 <- x2 + x3 + x4

object funtion 
min x5 + x6 

subject to
x1 + x2                <=  2
         x3 +  x4      <=  5
      x2    +  x4      <=  3
x1, x2, x3, x4 = binary
x5, x6 = integer

to do this by lpSolveAPI, I try it like below


lprec <- make.lp(3, 4) # make.lp
var_lp <- matrix(c( rep(1, 12)), nrow = 3) # variable as var_lp

set.column(lprec, 1, var_lp[1,1], indices = 1) # s.t.
set.column(lprec, 2, c(var_lp[1,2], var_lp[3,2], indices = c(1,3))
set.column(lprec, 3, var_lp[2,3], indices = 2)
set.column(lprec, 4, c(var_lp[2,4], var_lp[3,4], indices = c(2,3))
```

i don't know any more how to express x5, x6 at lpSolveAPI

Thank you for your leading. i hope someone give me a answer about that

*plus, my orignal data has about 5,000 constraint.
       is it possible to analyze by lpSolveAPI??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set.type` function allows you to specify integer domains

```
set.type(lprec, 5, type="integer")
```

You would need to increase your definition of the problem, though:

```
lprec <- make.lp(5,6)
```

Edit: Code fragment for this problem

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
lprec <- make.lp(5,6)
set.objfn(lprec, obj=c(1,1), indices=c(5,6)) # sense defaults to "min"
set.row(lprec, 1, xt=c(1,1), indices=c(1,2))
set.row(lprec, 2, xt=c(1,1), indices=c(3,4))
set.row(lprec, 3, xt=c(1,1), indices=c(2,4))
set.row(lprec, 4, xt=c(1,1,-1), indices=c(1,2,5))
set.row(lprec, 5, xt=c(1,1,1,-1), indices=c(2,3,4,6))
set.type(lprec, 1, type="binary")
set.type(lprec, 2, type="binary")
set.type(lprec, 3, type="binary")
set.type(lprec, 4, type="binary")
set.type(lprec, 5, type="integer")
set.type(lprec, 6, type="integer")
set.constr.type(lprec, types=c(rep("<=",3), rep("=",2)))
set.rhs(lprec, b=c(2,5,3,0,0))
```

You can use `print` or `write.lp` to check that the specified program is the program you want to solve. With `solve` you calculate the solution which would be in this all zero:

```
solve(lprec)
get.variables(lprec)
```

(I believe that implicitly, lpSolve assumes non-negativity of all variables.)

Comment: Thank you for your advisement.  and do you know how to express  x5, x6 at lpSolveAPI??  (x5 = x1 + x2, x6 = x2 + x3 + x4)

Comment: You may add x5, x6 as additional constraints, see edited answer.

Comment: I'm so Thank you for your help. I solve my lp problem. Have a good day :)